# Search for linkedin profile using Email

Tags: php, email, linkedin-api

I read about the LinkedIn API and found out that there's no way we can do a searching by just using email address. Is there another way to do this? I tried to search for my LinkedIn profile using Google search but there's no result. I tried different email address using this type of format: `<firstname>.<lastname>@gmail.com` and luckily I have the result.

I am planning to do this on PHP and embedd on my website.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I didn't notice it since I am new here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because there are **firstname.lastname** found in the web. Maybe what you are looking for is not yet available.